# Как подключить apollo client в Nextjs

Tags: typescript, websocket, nestjs, apollo-client

Пытаюсь подключить Apollo Client на Nextjs, но выходит ошибка:

```
Error: Unable to find native implementation, or alternative implementation for WebSocket!
```

Код подлючения:

```
  export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {

  const httpLink = new HttpLink({
    uri: 'http://localhost:8080/graphql'
  });
  
  const wsLink = new WebSocketLink({
    uri: `ws://localhost:8080/graphql`,
    options: {
      reconnect: true
    }
  });

  const splitLink = split(
    ({ query }) => {
      const definition = getMainDefinition(query);
      return (
        definition.kind === 'OperationDefinition' &&
        definition.operation === 'subscription'
      );
    },
    wsLink,
    httpLink,
  );

  const apolloClient = new ApolloClient({
    link: splitLink,
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  })

  return (
    <ApolloProvider client={apolloClient}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </ApolloProvider>
  )
}
```

На чистом react все без проблем запускается, а в next не хочет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел пример, который оставили разработчики Nextjs по graphql.
Cсылка: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-apollo
И дополнил его подключением через ws.
Вот код:

```
const wsLink = typeof window !== 'undefined' ? new WebSocketLink({
    uri: 'ws://localhost:8080/graphql',
    options: {
      reconnect: true
    }
  }) : null;
  
  const httplink = new HttpLink({
      uri: 'http://localhost:8080/graphql',
      credentials: 'same-origin'
  });
  
  const link = typeof window !== 'undefined' ? split(
    ({ query }) => {
      const definition = getMainDefinition(query);
      return (
        definition.kind === 'OperationDefinition' &&
        definition.operation === 'subscription'
      );
    },
    wsLink,
    httplink,
  ) : httplink;

const apolloClient = new ApolloClient({
    link,
    cache: new InMemoryCache()
});
```

Проблема была в том, что я пытался его подключить на сервере, что и вело к ошибке. Но после исправления клиент успешно смог подключиться.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]